# Python 3.6 / my function changes my global variables

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying really hard for my function not to mess my global 'b' value because I wish to re-use that list in another similar function using sets but it seems that even not using the same name (y), they (b and y) are still bound together...

most of the print lines are for debugging only as I was not understanding what was happening.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import random

a = random.sample(range(1,25),8)
b = random.sample(range(1,25),11)
a.sort()
b.sort()

def list_rdup(x,y):
    print('Loop remove duplicates:')
    print('x:',x)
    print('y:',y)
    for i in x:
        y.append(i)
    y.sort()
    print('y modified:',y)
    c = []
    for i in y:
        if i in c:
            pass
        else: 
            c.append(i)
    return c

print('a:',a)
print('b:',b)

print(list_rdup(a,b))

print('a:',a)
print('b:',b)
```

Output: we see a and b in their original state.. then I run the function and
print a and b again to show that b was modified in the process...

a: [1, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22]

**b: [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24]**

Loop remove duplicates:

x: [1, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22]

y: [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24]

y modified: [1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24]

[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24]

a: [1, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22]

**b: [1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24]**

Comment: Please note that too many short variable names can lead to shadowing mistakes. Making it meaningful is a good practice.

Comment: Then you will need to **copy** `a` and `b`. So call `list_rdup(a[:],b[:])`...

Comment: That is wonderful! I was expecting some suggestion for a local variable, that is even better than I thought!

Oh and on using longer variables, my real projects have them, this is for practice purposes only! thank you very much!

Comment: When you send a & b , actually you've sent the pointer to the list and not the values by themselves. So instead of list_rdup(a,b), send list_rdup(a[:],b[:]) as you send values instead of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The call `list_rdup(a,b)` simply passes the reference of a and b which are stored in x and y. So, any change in x and y will change a and b. If you do not want a and b to change make a copy by using `b_copy = b.copy()`.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid altering the elements, copy the array.

```
import random

a=[1, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22]
b=[1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24]
#a.sort()
#b.sort()

def list_rdup(x,y):
    print('Loop remove duplicates:')
    print('x:',x)
    print('y:',y)
    for i in x:
        y.append(i)
    y.sort()
    print('y modified:',y)
    c = []
    for i in y:
        if i in c:
            pass
        else: 
            c.append(i)
    return c

print('a:',a)
print('b:',b)

print(list_rdup(a[:], b[:]))

print('a:',a)
print('b:',b)
```

---

```
a: [1, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22]
b: [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24]
Loop remove duplicates:
x: [1, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22]
y: [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24]
y modified: [1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24]
a: [1, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 22]
b: [1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 24]
```

Also consider deep copying if you have non-primitive values in the array.

Comment: Terrible answer. 
If the idea is that the data is not chanegd, the copying should take place INSIDE the function - and not put on the caller the responsability to make a copy prior to calling it.

Please fix that - the way it is, this code is just harmful.

Comment: I doubt the idea. Copying is expensive, and it should be optional (in the case the caller can discard the data, it can omit the operation).